# Webdriver - Cannot locate Xpath/CSS getting NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am new to selenium and trying to find the correct xpath or CSS for the html code below and after spending so much time and after numerous trials I was not able to click on these elements and I need some help here. There seems to something very basic that I am missing here.I am getting NoSuchElementException.

**The 1st HTML:**

```
<input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value="" type="text">
```

I tried following code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="name"]")).sendKeys("Something");
driver.findElement(By.id("name")).sendKeys("Something");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='']")).sendKeys("Something");
```

**The 2nd HTML:**

```
<a href="#fragment2" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">
   <span>Module Permissions</span>
</a>
```

I tried following code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Module Permissions')]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Module Permissions")).click();
```

**My Test Env:**

1. Google Chrome Version 66.0.3359.181
2. Selenium WebDriver Version: 3.12

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: are you in an iframe?

Comment: search is` there any tag: `frame` or iframe` in the whole page HTML? If so you need to use switch to the frame where the element resides at first.

Comment: Yes, I was actuallly in an iframe. Once I switched to the iframe i was able to click on the element. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

1. It seems you got an error before sending keys. Is that only the code ? only input tag? if that is the case then try this.

   ```
   driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input")).sendKeys("Something");
   ```
2. Try this.

   ```
   driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a")).click();
   ```

much better if you provide the link of the page or whole html of the page